# Nokia 5110 LCD display doesn't work

Tags: lcd

Here is my circuit (all resistors are 10 kΩ, to lower the voltage, although I did try it without them with the same result):

[image: circuit]

The pinout on my display is (pin 1-8): RST, CE, DC, DIN, CLK, VCC, LIGHT, GND.

And here is my code:

```cpp
#include <Nokia_5110.h>
#define RST 6
#define CE 5
#define DC 4
#define DIN 3
#define CLK 2
Nokia_5110 lcd = Nokia_5110(RST, CE, DC, DIN, CLK);

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); //CLK
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //DIN
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //DC
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); //CE
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); //RST
  lcd.setContrast(60);
  lcd.setCursor(5, 2);
  lcd.print("Test");
}

void loop(){}
```

Problem is: nothing happens. I can only control the backlight via the potentiometer, but there is no text on the display. Now, this is my first attempt on this display so I might have just done something wrong; if you find it please tell me.

I'm using Nokia_5110.h library (https://github.com/baghayi/Nokia_5110)

Comment: Maybe show your actual display with its pinout. You have RST identified as Arduino pin 6 going to header pin 1 on the display.  RST is in the *middle* of the header on the one display I have that is like this. So, either your wiring is very wrong, or possibly more likely there's just no way to know because your display doesn't have the same pinout as mine.

Comment: @timemage the pinout on my display is (pin 1-8): RST, CE, DC, DIN, CLK, VCC, LIGHT, GND

Comment: Turns out I have a second one that's closer to that pinout, at least if old old pictures are to be believed. I don't see where you called `lcd.begin()`.

Comment: @timemage I was reverse engineering one of the example sketches (specifically, this one: https://github.com/baghayi/Nokia_5110/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.ino) from the guy who made the library that I am using and there was nothing like that. I also tried different other examples from the internet with other libraries and they had the same results

Comment: LOL. Alright, edit your question to show which library you're using, since you're not using the common one.

Comment: @timemage I'm using Nokia_5110.h library (https://github.com/baghayi/Nokia_5110)

Comment: As said, **[edit]** your answer. This is not a forum, please don't put important information in a comment. -- Why did you insert serial resistors?

Comment: Welcome! A labeled schematic even hand drawn would be much better than the frizzy picture you are displaying. It would show all the connections and pin numbers along with power and ground connections. 20 seconds with that will convey much more information then the frizzy thing will in 5 minutes.